# Jquery get request decapitalizing url string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get, steam-web-api

Here is my code:

```
            $.get('top secret url and stuff',function(data){
                console.log($("[style='color:white']", data.results_html)[0].innerHTML);
                window.html = document.createElement('div');
                window.html.innerHTML = data.results_html;
                console.log($('#resultlink_0', html)[0].href) // gets url from current page code
                $.get($('#resultlink_0', html)[0].href,function(data){
                    console.log(data)
                });
            });
```

When I console.log the url in the current page's code, it is capitalized fine. However, in the second get request, it decapitalizes all of the characters.

Here is an example of something it would decapitalize: "http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20Gut%20Knife%20%7C%20Safari%20Mesh%20(Battle-Scarred)".

Instead, it turns into this:
"http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/%E2%98%85%20gut%20knife%20%7C%20safari%20mesh%20(battle-scarred)".

I know this because, for one, the request isn't outputting what I want it to, and I also looked at fiddler and all of the characters in the request are decapitalized.

I need to fix this because said URL is case sensitive and will not work if the capital letters aren't actually capitalized.

Now: I don't know if this changes anything but I do have the chrome extension that allows cross-origin resource sharing on all websites.

Comment: *"for one, the request isn't outputting what I want it to,"* - That is a poor test. *"I also looked at fiddler"* - That's better, but have you also just checked your browser (F12, developer tools)? It shows the requests it does, including Ajax requests, and the response it gets. I can imagine you've got a [same origin policy issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: try using `attr('href')` instead of the `href` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. It turns out it was the CORS extension, so what I did was I had to disable CSP locally on steam's website to allow requests made to itself. For some odd reason steam won't even let you send requests to it's own site... on it's site... Thanks again.

~Aero